# Single website multiple databases, database switching

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have created a content management system (CMS) for my company’s product databases. The CMS is based on asp.net scaffolding with many custom pages and actions mixed in. We have 7 products currently, all of which share the same database schema (Entity Framework model-first) and all run perfectly in the CMS. The issue is that every time we get a new product we must clone the CMS and change the connection string in the `app.config` to point to the correct database in order to work with the new database. While this works, it’s becoming bothersome to maintain and will fail us completely as we acquire more products.

What I would like to do is have a centralized landing page where a user is directed to log in, then given the option to connect to and edit a specific product based on their selection. The idea is that we would have one CMS site which would be able to switch between the databases depending on the user. It is not an option to combine all of the product database in to a single master product database.

I am not sure where to start to achieve this goal, or if this is even the correct plan to achieve my goal of having a single CMS to maintain, and am looking for some guidance in this.

Comment: Doesn't sound like much of a CMS if you have to do ANYTHING when new content comes in...

Comment: That is to say, are you sure you don't have a more fundamental problem here? Or, perhaps, your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: No I am not sure I don't have a more fundamental problem. The product database system was created long before I join this company, and currently all of our offerings make the assumption that their product is the only product in the product database. That means we need a different product database for each product. I was simply looking for a way to have the CMS connect to the appropriate product database based on which product the author wanted to edit without have a specific CMS for each product.

Comment: Sounds like a fundamental design flaw to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your database structures are identical, you could use a factory method anywhere you get an instance of your entity context and put logic in there to grab the correct connection string (or calculate it if there's a naming convention that you could use). Something like this might work for example:

```
    public static MyDatabaseEntities CreateEntityContext(string productName)
    {
        string connectionString = null;
        switch (productName.Trim().ToLower())
        {
            case "apples":
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase_Apples"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case "pears":
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase_Pears"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            default:
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }
        return new MyDatabaseEntities(connectionString);
    }
```

Then use this method anywhere you need an instance of your CRM data context passing in the product name that you've calculated on your landing page.

Comment: perfect, I did not think about generating connection strings on the fly. I have a very predictable way of determining my connection strings. Thank you for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Create another database for user to database mapping. The structure would be like so:

```
database UserMap 

    table Users
       username (composite primary key)
       dbID (composite primary key, foreign key to "Databases" table)

    table Databases
       dbID (primary key)
       connectionString
```

Then,

1. populate the list of database in table "Databases"
2. Do your SQL work to copy the users from the other websites into this "UserMap" database
3. Write a trigger in each CMS database to add or remove a user as they are created or removed in their respective CMS so it updates the "UserMap" database
4. Modify your code on the CMS(s) to use this single database for lookup to what connection string should be used.

This would allow you to rely on the single database for the lookup and switch between them in a managed fashion going forward. It requires some up front work but after the triggers are there, you don't have to do anything more.

Comment: This is a very good method as well. Since I can predict the connection strings, I think the other method will work better for me.