# Connection string based on Location C#

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config, ini

I have one application that two different companies will use. I don't want to create two separate applications because when i need to fix bugs ill have to do it on both and I might loose track.

The only thing that differ from the two companies is Domain and DBs (Connection string) in other words separate networks. How can I get the app to use the right connection string based on where the user uses it from?? Example, Company A or Company B. I'm thinking of using a text or .ini file to store the connection strings.

Can someone please help or suggest something of the same sort?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to connect to both db from the same machine depending on user or one machine will Always connect to the same db?

Comment: @Steve One machine, one DB. In other words location A : All users will connect to one DB.

Comment: @Werner van den Heever Could you please clear this statement "based on location/domain or whatever.." Thing is when or based on what condition you want to change the connection string? It is not clear.

Comment: @Rezoan I have edited my question. Hope I cleared things up

Comment: @WernervandenHeever May be you can create a helper class that resolves your connectionstring based upon Company?

Comment: Here is a similar post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094265/single-website-multiple-databases-database-switching

Comment: Why you just don't use an app.config? In your build script when you deploy you update the connection string in app.config depending on who the deployment will be shipped to.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you :

It is better to use dropdown to select the company on login page to map with the user.
and on the basis of the user and company mapping you can select the connection string.
using if else clause.

Comment: Yes, I have considered this but its not the way I want to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to connect to DB using the first connection string. If it failed, use the other string. There may be some unexpected issues in this approach.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Although still not the correct way i think. Also, in the future more companies might be added.

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing that every machine of the two companies belong to different domains (as it should be) then you can retrieve the Domain name using

```
Environment.UserDomainName
```

and then build your connection string dinamically, for example at the startup of your application

```
static class Program
{
     public static string CompanyConnectionString;

     static void Main()
     {
          string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
          SqlConnectionStringBuilder sbc = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
          if(domain == "CompanyA")
          {
               sbc.DataSource = "ServerForComapanyA";
               sbc.InitialCatalog = "DataBaseCompanyA";
               ... etc ... 
               ... other properties of class SqlConnectionStringBuilder ...
               ... to exactly compose the connection string required
          }
          else if(domain == "CompanyB")
          {
               sbc.DataSource = "ServerForComapanyB";
               sbc.InitialCatalog = "DataBaseCompanyB";
               ... etc ... 
               ... other properties of class SqlConnectionStringBuilder ...
               ... to exactly compose the connection string required
          }
          else
          {
               MessabeBox.Show("Machine domain name not recognized. Unable to connect");
          }
          Program.ConnectionString = sbc.ConnectionString;
          ....
```

Now every class of your program could reference the startup class and use `Program.CompanyConnectionString`.
Of course, this work could also be moved to an utility class to resolve dependency on the main class

[SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)
[Environment.UserDomainName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx)

Just realized that I don't know if you use Sql Server or not, but the [ConnectionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class is available also for OleDb, Odbc, Oracle and probably every other major provider has the same

Answer (score 0):

Use an app.config. In your build script when you deploy you update the connection string in app.config depending on who the deployment will be shipped to.