# how to connect multiple database with single application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need your  to help to short out my problem. i m trying to connect my web application to different database. user select the database from user interface i.e asp.net page.the application will connect with that database.

for that i tried to make initial catalog dynamic but not get success. please help.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string db = "";
    if (ddlDropdown.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        if (ddlDropdown.SelectedItem.Value == "2013")
        {
            db = "2013";
        }

        if (ddlDropdown.SelectedItem.Value == "2014")
        {
            db = "2014";
        }
    }
    string abc = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=" + db + ";Integrated Security=True";
    Session["abc"] = abc;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(abc);
    con.Open();
    Response.Redirect("rrr.aspx");
}
```

Comment: And there you have an open database connection. But I don't see what error you may encounter or what you want to achieve?

Comment: Any error message or exception?

Comment: please share your design code aswell.

Comment: What happen when SelectedIndex is zero or -1?

Comment: @Steve: i feel OP Should assign `db` value to some default Database instead of initializing to empty string.

Comment: yeah thats true, he just need to specify default_db_name while assigning to db

Comment: why do you open a connection to a database and after directly change the page ? Are you get some exception between the connection to db and the redirect ?

Comment: for multiple connections check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094265/single-website-multiple-databases-database-switching

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlserver database system then just connect with one database in connection string, and while accessing tables of another database just use following syntax:

```
select * from databasename..tablename
```

`databasename..tablename` do works.

you can also use ti as follows:

```
select * from databasename..tablename t
where t.columnname=value
```

Try it.

Comment: no i don't want this.. i want to connect seprate database.. suppose user select 2013 than the application connect with 2013 database if user select 2014 than the application connect with 2014 database.same thing  for other years...

Comment: @user3085836 things you are mentioning will increase overhead of your application

Comment: @user3085836 in that case ur above code(with some modifications) will also work, what is problem in it?

Comment: Though it is a technically correct answer, it is really a pain to add the name of the database and the two points at every table, view, or stored procedure

Comment: @Steve hahaha...as if we writes so many points to have join query...then why to feel pain in adding extra point?

Comment: @Steve in the case u mentioned, user can also have instance of dbname..tablename which he can use each time

Comment: @friend : prblem is that this code is not working .. when i m using this    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Session ["abc"].ToString()); the sessios key word showing error..

Comment: @user3085836 try using getthesessionvariable("abc") in your code

Comment: @FRIENDS Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'